# How to loop through JSON responses inside Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to import Data from the Snapchat API inside Google Sheets (Documentation found here: https://marketingapi.snapchat.com/docs/?shell#get-all-ad-squads-under-a-campaign).

At the moment I am doing that in an inefficient way, by plotting the results one at a time. I want, instead, to plot them using a loop, if possible.

Currently, this is my code:

```
function readData() {

var accesstoken = "TOKEN"

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

 var adseturl = "https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/campaigns/e431cbcd-2281-49fe-8d05-b26c87660eb5/adsquads"
 var adseturlresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(adseturl, {
       headers: {
           "Authorization": "Bearer " + accesstoken
       }
   });

var adsetdata = JSON.parse(adseturlresponse.getContentText());
var adsetname1range = sheet.getRange('C3')
var adsetname2range = sheet.getRange('C4')
var adsetname3range = sheet.getRange('C5')
var adsetname4range = sheet.getRange('C6')
var adsetname5range = sheet.getRange('C7')
var adsetname6range = sheet.getRange('C8')
var adsetname7range = sheet.getRange('C9')
var adsetname8range = sheet.getRange('C10')

var adsetname1= adsetdata.adsquads[0].adsquad.name
adsetname1range.setValue(adsetname1)
    
var adsetname2= adsetdata.adsquads[1].adsquad.name  
adsetname2range.setValue(adsetname2)

var adsetname3= adsetdata.adsquads[2].adsquad.name
adsetname3range.setValue(adsetname3)

var adsetname4= adsetdata.adsquads[3].adsquad.name 
adsetname4range.setValue(adsetname4)

var adsetname5= adsetdata.adsquads[4].adsquad.name  
adsetname5range.setValue(adsetname5)

var adsetname6= adsetdata.adsquads[5].adsquad.name
 adsetname6range.setValue(adsetname6)

var adsetname7= adsetdata.adsquads[6].adsquad.name  
adsetname7range.setValue(adsetname7)

var adsetname8= adsetdata.adsquads[7].adsquad.name     
adsetname8range.setValue(adsetname8)

}
```

As you can see, I am plotting my results one by one, like this:

```
var adsetdata = JSON.parse(adseturlresponse.getContentText());
var adsetname1range = sheet.getRange('C3')
var adsetname2range = sheet.getRange('C4')
var adsetname3range = sheet.getRange('C5')
var adsetname4range = sheet.getRange('C6')
var adsetname5range = sheet.getRange('C7')
var adsetname6range = sheet.getRange('C8')
var adsetname7range = sheet.getRange('C9')
var adsetname8range = sheet.getRange('C10')

var adsetname1= adsetdata.adsquads[0].adsquad.name
adsetname1range.setValue(adsetname1)
    
var adsetname2= adsetdata.adsquads[1].adsquad.name  
adsetname2range.setValue(adsetname2)

var adsetname3= adsetdata.adsquads[2].adsquad.name
adsetname3range.setValue(adsetname3)

var adsetname4= adsetdata.adsquads[3].adsquad.name 
adsetname4range.setValue(adsetname4)

var adsetname5= adsetdata.adsquads[4].adsquad.name  
adsetname5range.setValue(adsetname5)

var adsetname6= adsetdata.adsquads[5].adsquad.name
 adsetname6range.setValue(adsetname6)

var adsetname7= adsetdata.adsquads[6].adsquad.name  
adsetname7range.setValue(adsetname7)

var adsetname8= adsetdata.adsquads[7].adsquad.name     
adsetname8range.setValue(adsetname8)
```

But instead, I want to be able to loop through

```
adsetdata.adsquads[i].adsquad.name
```

Also, here my results are from "C3:C10" but the number of rows is dynamic depending on the number of results.

Thank you for your input in how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var adsetname1range = sheet.getRange('C3')
var adsetname2range = sheet.getRange('C4')
var adsetname3range = sheet.getRange('C5')
var adsetname4range = sheet.getRange('C6')
var adsetname5range = sheet.getRange('C7')
var adsetname6range = sheet.getRange('C8')
var adsetname7range = sheet.getRange('C9')
var adsetname8range = sheet.getRange('C10')

var adsetname1= adsetdata.adsquads[0].adsquad.name
adsetname1range.setValue(adsetname1)
    
var adsetname2= adsetdata.adsquads[1].adsquad.name  
adsetname2range.setValue(adsetname2)

var adsetname3= adsetdata.adsquads[2].adsquad.name
adsetname3range.setValue(adsetname3)

var adsetname4= adsetdata.adsquads[3].adsquad.name 
adsetname4range.setValue(adsetname4)

var adsetname5= adsetdata.adsquads[4].adsquad.name  
adsetname5range.setValue(adsetname5)

var adsetname6= adsetdata.adsquads[5].adsquad.name
 adsetname6range.setValue(adsetname6)

var adsetname7= adsetdata.adsquads[6].adsquad.name  
adsetname7range.setValue(adsetname7)

var adsetname8= adsetdata.adsquads[7].adsquad.name     
adsetname8range.setValue(adsetname8)
```

#### To:

```
var values = adsetdata.adsquads.map(({ adsquad: { name } }) => [name]);
sheet.getRange(3, 3, values.length).setValues(values);
```

- When this modified script is run, the values are retrieved from an aray of `adsetdata.adsquads` and put to column "C".

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hi, could you please have a look at this ? I'm trying to divide my JSON response value by a number :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75906184/how-to-divide-a-variable-in-apps-script