# Apps Script - If Google Sheets Named Ranges contain specific text, then apply an action to those ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tables where information is plotted in 10 rows of each table. My code hides rows from those tables depending on a cell number.

If the cell number is 1, the table will only show the first row out of 10.

If the cell number is 2, the table will show the first 2 rows out of 10.

etc...

**Here's my code:**

```
function HideRows() {
  var amexlivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("amexlivecampaigns").getValues();
  var bandqlivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("bandqlivecampaigns").getValues();
  var cofiquelivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("cofiquelivecampaigns").getValues();
  var freshlooklivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("freshlooklivecampaigns").getValues()
    ;
  var gcslivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("gcslivecampaigns").getValues();
  var homeboxlivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("homeboxlivecampaigns").getValues();
  var mcdlivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("mcdlivecampaigns").getValues();
  var musichalllivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("musichalllivecampaigns").getValues();
  var trevalivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("trevalivecampaigns").getValues();
  var uhclivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("uhclivecampaigns").getValues();

  var rangeName = "amexlivecampaigns";
  var range = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName);
  var rangeName2 = "bandqlivecampaigns";
  var range2 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName2);
  var rangeName3 = "cofiquelivecampaigns";
  var range3 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName3);
  var rangeName4 = "freshlooklivecampaigns";
  var range4 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName4)
    ;
  var rangeName5 = "gcslivecampaigns";
  var range5 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName5);
  var rangeName6 = "homeboxlivecampaigns";
  var range6 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName6)
    ;
  var rangeName7 = "mcdlivecampaigns";
  var range7 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName7);
  var rangeName8 = "musichalllivecampaigns";
  var range8 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName8)
    ;
  var rangeName9 = "trevalivecampaigns";
  var range9 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName9)
    ;
  var rangeName10 = "uhclivecampaigns";
  var range10 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName10)
    ;

  for (var i = 0; i < amexlivedata.length; i++) {

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(range.getRow(), 9 + range.getNumRows());
    }
    if (amexlivedata[i][1] == 1) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range.getRow(), 8 + range.getNumRows());
    }
    if (amexlivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range.getRow(), 7 + range.getNumRows());
    }

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] == 3) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range.getRow(), 6 + range.getNumRows());
    }

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] === 4) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(4 + range.getRow(), 5 + range.getNumRows());
    }

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] == 5) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(5 + range.getRow(), 4 + range.getNumRows());
    }

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] === 6) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(6 + range.getRow(), 3 + range.getNumRows());
    }

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] == 7) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(7 + range.getRow(), 2 + range.getNumRows());
    }

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] == 8) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(8 + range.getRow(), 1 + range.getNumRows());
    }

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] == 9) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(9 + range.getRow(), range.getNumRows());
    }

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] == 10) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < bandqlivedata.length; i++) {

    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
      range2.getSheet().hideRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
    }
    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] == 1) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
      range2.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range2.getRow(), 8 + range2.getNumRows());
    }
    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
      range2.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range2.getRow(), 7 + range2.getNumRows());
    }

    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] == 3) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
      range2.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range2.getRow(), 6 + range2.getNumRows());
    }

    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] === 4) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
      range2.getSheet().hideRows(4 + range2.getRow(), 5 + range2.getNumRows());
    }

    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] == 5) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
      range2.getSheet().hideRows(5 + range2.getRow(), 4 + range2.getNumRows());
    }

    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] === 6) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
      range2.getSheet().hideRows(6 + range2.getRow(), 3 + range2.getNumRows());
    }

    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] == 7) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
      range2.getSheet().hideRows(7 + range2.getRow(), 2 + range2.getNumRows());
    }

    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] == 8) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
      range2.getSheet().hideRows(8 + range2.getRow(), 1 + range2.getNumRows());
    }

    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] == 9) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
      range2.getSheet().hideRows(9 + range2.getRow(), range2.getNumRows());
    }

    if (bandqlivedata[i][1] == 10) {

      range2.getSheet().showRows(range2.getRow(), 10 + range2.getNumRows());
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < cofiquelivedata.length; i++) {

    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
      range3.getSheet().hideRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
    }
    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] == 1) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
      range3.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range3.getRow(), 8 + range3.getNumRows());
    }
    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
      range3.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range3.getRow(), 7 + range3.getNumRows());
    }

    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] == 3) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
      range3.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range3.getRow(), 6 + range3.getNumRows());
    }

    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] === 4) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
      range3.getSheet().hideRows(4 + range3.getRow(), 5 + range3.getNumRows());
    }

    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] == 5) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
      range3.getSheet().hideRows(5 + range3.getRow(), 4 + range3.getNumRows());
    }

    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] === 6) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
      range3.getSheet().hideRows(6 + range3.getRow(), 3 + range3.getNumRows());
    }

    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] == 7) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
      range3.getSheet().hideRows(7 + range3.getRow(), 2 + range3.getNumRows());
    }

    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] == 8) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
      range3.getSheet().hideRows(8 + range3.getRow(), 1 + range3.getNumRows());
    }

    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] == 9) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
      range3.getSheet().hideRows(9 + range3.getRow(), range3.getNumRows());
    }

    if (cofiquelivedata[i][1] == 10) {

      range3.getSheet().showRows(range3.getRow(), 10 + range3.getNumRows());
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < freshlooklivedata.length; i++) {

    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
      range4.getSheet().hideRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
    }
    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] == 1) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
      range4.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range4.getRow(), 8 + range4.getNumRows());
    }
    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
      range4.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range4.getRow(), 7 + range4.getNumRows());
    }

    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] == 3) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
      range4.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range4.getRow(), 6 + range4.getNumRows());
    }

    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] === 4) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
      range4.getSheet().hideRows(4 + range4.getRow(), 5 + range4.getNumRows());
    }

    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] == 5) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
      range4.getSheet().hideRows(5 + range4.getRow(), 4 + range4.getNumRows());
    }

    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] === 6) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
      range4.getSheet().hideRows(6 + range4.getRow(), 3 + range4.getNumRows());
    }

    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] == 7) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
      range4.getSheet().hideRows(7 + range4.getRow(), 2 + range4.getNumRows());
    }

    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] == 8) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
      range4.getSheet().hideRows(8 + range4.getRow(), 1 + range4.getNumRows());
    }

    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] == 9) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
      range4.getSheet().hideRows(9 + range4.getRow(), range4.getNumRows());
    }

    if (freshlooklivedata[i][1] == 10) {

      range4.getSheet().showRows(range4.getRow(), 10 + range4.getNumRows());
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < gcslivedata.length; i++) {

    if (gcslivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
      range5.getSheet().hideRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
    }
    if (gcslivedata[i][1] == 1) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
      range5.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range5.getRow(), 8 + range5.getNumRows());
    }
    if (gcslivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
      range5.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range5.getRow(), 7 + range5.getNumRows());
    }

    if (gcslivedata[i][1] == 3) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
      range5.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range5.getRow(), 6 + range5.getNumRows());
    }

    if (gcslivedata[i][1] === 4) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
      range5.getSheet().hideRows(4 + range5.getRow(), 5 + range5.getNumRows());
    }

    if (gcslivedata[i][1] == 5) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
      range5.getSheet().hideRows(5 + range5.getRow(), 4 + range5.getNumRows());
    }

    if (gcslivedata[i][1] === 6) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
      range5.getSheet().hideRows(6 + range5.getRow(), 3 + range5.getNumRows());
    }

    if (gcslivedata[i][1] == 7) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
      range5.getSheet().hideRows(7 + range5.getRow(), 2 + range5.getNumRows());
    }

    if (gcslivedata[i][1] == 8) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
      range5.getSheet().hideRows(8 + range5.getRow(), 1 + range5.getNumRows());
    }

    if (gcslivedata[i][1] == 9) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
      range5.getSheet().hideRows(9 + range5.getRow(), range5.getNumRows());
    }

    if (gcslivedata[i][1] == 10) {

      range5.getSheet().showRows(range5.getRow(), 10 + range5.getNumRows());
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < homeboxlivedata.length; i++) {

    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
      range6.getSheet().hideRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
    }
    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] == 1) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
      range6.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range6.getRow(), 8 + range6.getNumRows());
    }
    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
      range6.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range6.getRow(), 7 + range6.getNumRows());
    }

    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] == 3) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
      range6.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range6.getRow(), 6 + range6.getNumRows());
    }

    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] === 4) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
      range6.getSheet().hideRows(4 + range6.getRow(), 5 + range6.getNumRows());
    }

    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] == 5) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
      range6.getSheet().hideRows(5 + range6.getRow(), 4 + range6.getNumRows());
    }

    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] === 6) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
      range6.getSheet().hideRows(6 + range6.getRow(), 3 + range6.getNumRows());
    }

    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] == 7) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
      range6.getSheet().hideRows(7 + range6.getRow(), 2 + range6.getNumRows());
    }

    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] == 8) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
      range6.getSheet().hideRows(8 + range6.getRow(), 1 + range6.getNumRows());
    }

    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] == 9) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
      range6.getSheet().hideRows(9 + range6.getRow(), range6.getNumRows());
    }

    if (homeboxlivedata[i][1] == 10) {

      range6.getSheet().showRows(range6.getRow(), 10 + range6.getNumRows());
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < mcdlivedata.length; i++) {

    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
      range7.getSheet().hideRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
    }
    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] == 1) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
      range7.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range7.getRow(), 8 + range7.getNumRows());
    }
    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
      range7.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range7.getRow(), 7 + range7.getNumRows());
    }

    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] == 3) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
      range7.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range7.getRow(), 6 + range7.getNumRows());
    }

    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] === 4) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
      range7.getSheet().hideRows(4 + range7.getRow(), 5 + range7.getNumRows());
    }

    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] == 5) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
      range7.getSheet().hideRows(5 + range7.getRow(), 4 + range7.getNumRows());
    }

    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] === 6) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
      range7.getSheet().hideRows(6 + range7.getRow(), 3 + range7.getNumRows());
    }

    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] == 7) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
      range7.getSheet().hideRows(7 + range7.getRow(), 2 + range7.getNumRows());
    }

    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] == 8) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
      range7.getSheet().hideRows(8 + range7.getRow(), 1 + range7.getNumRows());
    }

    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] == 9) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
      range7.getSheet().hideRows(9 + range7.getRow(), range7.getNumRows());
    }

    if (mcdlivedata[i][1] == 10) {

      range7.getSheet().showRows(range7.getRow(), 10 + range7.getNumRows());
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < musichalllivedata.length; i++) {

    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
      range8.getSheet().hideRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
    }
    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] === 1) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
      range8.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range8.getRow(), 8 + range8.getNumRows());
    }
    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
      range8.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range8.getRow(), 7 + range8.getNumRows());
    }

    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] === 3) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
      range8.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range8.getRow(), 6 + range8.getNumRows());
    }

    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] === 4) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
      range8.getSheet().hideRows(4 + range8.getRow(), 5 + range8.getNumRows());
    }

    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] == 5) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
      range8.getSheet().hideRows(5 + range8.getRow(), 4 + range8.getNumRows());
    }

    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] === 6) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
      range8.getSheet().hideRows(6 + range8.getRow(), 3 + range8.getNumRows());
    }

    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] == 7) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
      range8.getSheet().hideRows(7 + range8.getRow(), 2 + range8.getNumRows());
    }

    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] == 8) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
      range8.getSheet().hideRows(8 + range8.getRow(), 1 + range8.getNumRows());
    }

    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] == 9) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
      range8.getSheet().hideRows(9 + range8.getRow(), range8.getNumRows());
    }

    if (musichalllivedata[i][1] == 10) {

      range8.getSheet().showRows(range8.getRow(), 10 + range8.getNumRows());
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < trevalivedata.length; i++) {

    if (trevalivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
      range9.getSheet().hideRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
    }
    if (trevalivedata[i][1] == 1) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
      range9.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range9.getRow(), 8 + range9.getNumRows());
    }
    if (trevalivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
      range9.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range9.getRow(), 7 + range9.getNumRows());
    }

    if (trevalivedata[i][1] == 3) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
      range9.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range9.getRow(), 6 + range9.getNumRows());
    }

    if (trevalivedata[i][1] === 4) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
      range9.getSheet().hideRows(4 + range9.getRow(), 5 + range9.getNumRows());
    }

    if (trevalivedata[i][1] == 5) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
      range9.getSheet().hideRows(5 + range9.getRow(), 4 + range9.getNumRows());
    }

    if (trevalivedata[i][1] === 6) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
      range9.getSheet().hideRows(6 + range9.getRow(), 3 + range9.getNumRows());
    }

    if (trevalivedata[i][1] == 7) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
      range9.getSheet().hideRows(7 + range9.getRow(), 2 + range9.getNumRows());
    }

    if (trevalivedata[i][1] == 8) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
      range9.getSheet().hideRows(8 + range9.getRow(), 1 + range9.getNumRows());
    }

    if (trevalivedata[i][1] == 9) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
      range9.getSheet().hideRows(9 + range9.getRow(), range9.getNumRows());
    }

    if (trevalivedata[i][1] == 10) {

      range9.getSheet().showRows(range9.getRow(), 10 + range9.getNumRows());
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < uhclivedata.length; i++) {

    if (uhclivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
      range10.getSheet().hideRows(range10.getRow(), 9 + range10.getNumRows());
    }
    if (uhclivedata[i][1] == 1) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
      range10.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range10.getRow(), 8 + range10.getNumRows());
    }
    if (uhclivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
      range10.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range10.getRow(), 7 + range10.getNumRows());
    }

    if (uhclivedata[i][1] == 3) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
      range10.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range10.getRow(), 6 + range10.getNumRows());
    }

    if (uhclivedata[i][1] === 4) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
      range10.getSheet().hideRows(4 + range10.getRow(), 5 + range10.getNumRows());
    }

    if (uhclivedata[i][1] == 5) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
      range10.getSheet().hideRows(5 + range10.getRow(), 4 + range10.getNumRows());
    }

    if (uhclivedata[i][1] === 6) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
      range10.getSheet().hideRows(6 + range10.getRow(), 3 + range10.getNumRows());
    }

    if (uhclivedata[i][1] == 7) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
      range10.getSheet().hideRows(7 + range10.getRow(), 2 + range10.getNumRows());
    }

    if (uhclivedata[i][1] == 8) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
      range10.getSheet().hideRows(8 + range10.getRow(), 1 + range10.getNumRows());
    }

    if (uhclivedata[i][1] == 9) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
      range10.getSheet().hideRows(9 + range10.getRow(), range10.getNumRows());
    }

    if (uhclivedata[i][1] == 10) {

      range10.getSheet().showRows(range10.getRow(), 10 + range10.getNumRows());
    }
  }
}
```

**Explaining my code:**

I am first defining the values variables of my Named Ranges which will tell the script the number of rows to show/hide.

```
var amexlivedata = statusinfospreadsheet.getRange("amexlivecampaigns").getValues();
```

etc...

I am then defining the ranges which will hide/show depending on the above var values:

```
var rangeName = "amexlivecampaigns";
  var range = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName);
  var rangeName2 = "bandqlivecampaigns";
  var range2 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName2);
  var rangeName3 = "cofiquelivecampaigns";
  var range3 = getactivespreadsheet.getRangeByName(rangeName3);
```

etc...

I am then writing the if condition which will hide/show the named ranges rows depending on the cell number defined from var values

```
for (var i = 0; i < amexlivedata.length; i++) {

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] === 0) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(range.getRow(), 9 + range.getNumRows());
    }
    if (amexlivedata[i][1] == 1) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(1 + range.getRow(), 8 + range.getNumRows());
    }
    if (amexlivedata[i][1] === 2) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(2 + range.getRow(), 7 + range.getNumRows());
    }

    if (amexlivedata[i][1] == 3) {

      range.getSheet().showRows(range.getRow(), 10 + range.getNumRows());
      range.getSheet().hideRows(3 + range.getRow(), 6 + range.getNumRows());
    }
```

etc... until 10 and for each client

**The challenge:**

Those tables represent clients, and each time I add a client, I have to do this process manually.

**My question:**

Is there a way to loop or map Named Ranges that contain specific text (in my case, the text "live") and apply my script on all those ranges at once ? So that every time I add a new named range that contains the text "Live", the script includes this new named range and applies the script action on it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: About your comment on my previous answer of `hello, could you please have a look at my new question? stackoverflow.com/questions/75948275/…`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And, what does `tables where information is plotted in 10 rows of each table.` mean? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike hello and thank you for your kind ongoing support. To make things clear, I have created a copy sheet for you to see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1coAyxkzkaKuYooOACnwfPZk9Ei_HQV2KUQ2eTf_yLTw/edit#gid=157426791
Each table(seperated by colors) represents a client, and in each table there is 10 rows that display information. My script hides rows of each table depending on the number in Column B. for example, If the number is 1, only 1 row from the table will appear and 9 rows will hide, if the number is 2, 2 rows will appear and 8 rows will hide, etc..

Comment: @Tanaike Also regarding input and output sample, my goal is as follows : When I create a new table and create a named range from the new table, I want the new namedrange to be included in my hide/show row script if the namedrange contains the text "live".

Comment: @Tanaike I have modified the spreadsheet and added a sheet tab to correctly display the input and output situation, in the table for "NEW CLIENT". I want to achieve this result by creating a NamedRange and hiding/showing rows depending on Column B value number. I am able to achieve this with my script, but it is inefficient because everytime I add a new client, I have to manually add this information to my code. Is there a way to group, or map/loop this action to all NamedRanged that contain specific text ? In my case, all my namedranges contain the text "live".

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, if you could please have a look at my question, I would be grateful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76276831/embedding-facebook-ad-preview-iframe-to-google-slides-using-google-apps-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to hide rows by the values of column "B".
- For example, when the value of column "B" is 1, you want to show one row.

When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, the named ranges are incomplete. By this, I thought that your goal cannot be achieved using the named ranges. From this situation, in this answer, as a simple method, I would like to propose a sample script without using the named ranges. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

From your provided Spreadsheet, I used a sheet name `INPUT`. Please modify this for your actual situation.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INPUT");
  sheet.getRange("A5:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues()
    .forEach((e, i) => {
      if (e[0] && e[1].toString()) {
        const row = i + 5;
        sheet.hideRows(row, 10);
        sheet.showRows(row, e[1]);
      }
    });
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [hideRows(rowIndex, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideRows(Integer,Integer))
- [showRows(rowIndex, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showrowsrowindex,-numrows)

Comment: thank you for your kind support and efforts. The script is working but it is only hiding/showing the "NEW CLIENT" table. Is it possible to modify the script  to apply the hide rows to all the tables available ?

Comment: Your code is perfect. It was already hiding rows of all table but I wasn't running it correctly. I was able to modify my script to my need. Also, your idea is much better than mine. Amazing work as usual Tanaike, thank you very much for your kind and ongoing support, I highly appreciate your time. Thank you again my friend!