# Embedding Facebook Ad Preview iframe to Google Slides Dialog Box using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, facebook-graph-api, google-slides

I have the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/${creativeId}/previews?ad_format=INSTAGRAM_STANDARD&access_token=${TOKEN}`
```

That fetches the following result:

```
"<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/ads/api/preview_iframe.php?d=AQIQOVf73lc6gE6oZk_KlQhYCyodDecQS2Ki8EVXur8CfNiuGySpoiBdsUkdXRaq3UlWgoIyN46_M1k05zrIBPAFS3AlLTYlznM095OJdK6T3dPhpXMGN5m-jaj27zMwURMeI9fLG5fXDd_6jOECJdvSktJk84ESLZfCiV-0n1az_2pBhi-DdsQxNlOT0fJImOlNKEwS3O8t2hZ5pRLJuKufc_LK5CaGgU866dwHwntEjVxRH6JHsBeG1ipj8gAf3gm_QVrSsBGEdb-JhV9NysDjf1GNc7ZLQCU4eL0Dm4sZJ3zxH0nQMvmSbaEYOT9DFSerAKHRmX5c6FQvwAP6ev_fFhqi3jujuX3nFxWfFSCXLgeRHf_Hd0fxvLdAecSecsTjKcsVRgPTKfbMp2JBdEWsHgFCnsl0-xL5KLsPmGMlQsaAtmubZHtmwpcutlCj9Cs&amp;t=AQLQVw_wsM5j3L7j2YI\" width=\"320\" height=\"525\" scrolling=\"yes\" style=\"border: none;\"></iframe>`
```

The results has the below ad preview url link:
`https://www.facebook.com/ads/api/preview_iframe.php?d=AQIWqcCZ4MvRL0Vs54fOKgjz_wqefwfmh6I0LDIUHt6ske4OIq-XVSvit7eMBIHiB-2heObno8DCpxSjQUmQSN5Ex1CQ8gJULFkCbn3lyli9b0r8wTzeOn_tBS1WyZU1EUfB16oJ--EZcTBhuP7sfBplKKTllnJMHHqcru-1VdCaVg4TM7hVwo2FHda8hgyHuQekSO_oEe1gmfZqhxRquLhZHnFVOyMIx2EBGAwhoJDMDAHbyJRrYas_kpiEnu386jbyo2S96XbXWuaPRo81WOq7JDtgQy4KEVCLZ8J1jjdD1s6Vm86oRYUqiHEG2seYrR3ZQq6W1dKs9XPnnJb_QQ7nBXtBqsObZXLGMCIvZMbNe_V7oOx-MqXandQWHL62fVaccEynk2h5VnJ6X3wWXC865OKjw3hCfy8PJ2R9PeuskqyAyR0yRg0QWA32g1x6j6s&amp&t=AQIvJJ9tem1--9rT7QE`

Is there a way to embed the above Ad preview creative in Google Slides Dialog Box ? If not, are there any alternatives or workarounds to do so ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I saw this question from your comment `Hello @Tanaike, if you could please have a look at my question, I would be grateful : stackoverflow.com/questions/76276831/…` in my answer. It seems that in the case of your provided URL, the page is dynamically created by the script. In this case, unfortunately, I think that your goal cannot be achieved. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, for example, I think that when a dialog and sidebar are used, it can be achieved. If this was not included in your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, when you say `when a dialog and sidebar are used, it can be achieved` could you please provide more details about this ? Also regarding my expected result, I want the creative object from the ad preview url to appear in google slides.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `when you say when a dialog and sidebar are used, it can be achieved could you please provide more details about this ?`, in this case, your iframe is shown in a dialog and a sidebar on Slides. About `I want the creative object from the ad preview url to appear in google slides.`, if you want to insert your iframe into a slide in Google Slides, unfortunately, this cannot be achieved.

Comment: In this case, could you please show me how to insert the iframe into a dialog box ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `In this case, could you please show me how to insert the iframe into a dialog box ?`, in this case, the script cannot be put into a comment. So, it is required to post it as an answer. But, I'm worried that showing it in a dialog might not be your expected result from `I want the creative object from the ad preview url to appear in google slides.`. If you want to show it in a dialog, can you update your question?

Comment: I edited my question, but in my original question, I also asked if there was a workaround, so your answer could work. But no problem, I changed my question now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to show `<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/`,,,">` to a dialog on Google Slides.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Slides.

```js
function sample() {
  // This value is from your question.
  const html = '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/ads/api/preview_iframe.php?d=AQIQOVf73lc6gE6oZk_KlQhYCyodDecQS2Ki8EVXur8CfNiuGySpoiBdsUkdXRaq3UlWgoIyN46_M1k05zrIBPAFS3AlLTYlznM095OJdK6T3dPhpXMGN5m-jaj27zMwURMeI9fLG5fXDd_6jOECJdvSktJk84ESLZfCiV-0n1az_2pBhi-DdsQxNlOT0fJImOlNKEwS3O8t2hZ5pRLJuKufc_LK5CaGgU866dwHwntEjVxRH6JHsBeG1ipj8gAf3gm_QVrSsBGEdb-JhV9NysDjf1GNc7ZLQCU4eL0Dm4sZJ3zxH0nQMvmSbaEYOT9DFSerAKHRmX5c6FQvwAP6ev_fFhqi3jujuX3nFxWfFSCXLgeRHf_Hd0fxvLdAecSecsTjKcsVRgPTKfbMp2JBdEWsHgFCnsl0-xL5KLsPmGMlQsaAtmubZHtmwpcutlCj9Cs&amp;t=AQLQVw_wsM5j3L7j2YI" width="320" height="525" scrolling="yes" style="border: none;"></iframe>';

  SlidesApp
    .getUi()
    .showModalDialog(
      HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
        .setWidth(400)
        .setHeight(600),
      "sample"
    );
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This is a sample script. So, please modify this to your actual situation.
- If you want to show it in a sidebar, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      SlidesApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).setWidth(400).setHeight(600), "sample");
    ```
  - To

    ```
      SlidesApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL));
    ```

#### References:

- [getUi() of Class SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app#getui)
- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

Comment: it worked! is it possible to assign the script to a button inside a slide ?

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying and testing it. About `is it possible to assign the script to a button inside a slide ?`, in the current stage, the function cannot be assigned to the drawing and image. Even when the URL of Web Apps is set to a drawing, the dialog cannot be opened. So, in this case, how about opening the dialog from a custom menu and a sidebar?

Comment: Ok, no problem. I'll do that. Thank you Tanaike for your usual support  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Karim Thank you for replying. For example, when you open a dialog from a sidebar, when you run `SlidesApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="google.script.run.sample()">'))`, a sidebar is opened on Google Slides. And, when you click "ok" button on the sidebar, `sample()` of the above script is run.

Comment: oh this is nice! Thank you for showing me this method. I can work something out with this. Thank you!