# How do you access the"resourceName" from the Response body when creating a new contact with the People API via Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

This is probably a basic scripting question but I have limited coding experience and most solutions I have  find around this refer to HTML calls via JSON.  I am trying to do this via apps script...

I have sucessfully coded to draw the relevant info from Google Sheets and create individiual contacts. I also have code to update the CoverPic but to do this I need to get the "resourceName" (person.id) from the response body created by the Method: people.createContact

I have [read](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact#response-body) that if the creation of the contact is sucessful the the response body contains an instance of [Person](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person).

The closest answer I have found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75846207/how-to-read-json-response-body-inside-apps-script). But this addresses the problem of getting the responseBody via a JSON parse which in turn is derived from a URL call.

If I understand correctly, the response body includes the "resourceName" as a string but I don't have the knowledge of how to access this via Apps scipt.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? And, can you provide your current script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.